# Why is it called a quadratic if it only contains $x^2$, not $x^4$?

Tags: quadratics

Why is it called a quadratic if it only contains $x^2$, not $x^4$? Should it not be bidratic or didratic etc?

Comment: [Quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)

Comment: $(x+a)^2$ is the area of a square of side $x+a$ (in some languages square is literally "quadrate").

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but. A square has.. **four corners** and **four sides**.

Answer (score 9):

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadratic.html

> The Latin prefix *quadri*- is used to indicate the number $4$, for
>   example, quadrilateral, quadrant, etc. However, it also very commonly
>   used to denote objects involving the number $2$. This is the case
>   because *quadratum* is the Latin word for square, and since the area of
>   a square of side length $x$ is given by $x^2$, a polynomial equation
>   having exponent two is known as a quadratic ("square-like") equation.
>   By extension, a quadratic surface is a *second*-order algebraic surface.
>
> By analogy, since the volume of a cube of side length $x$ is $x^3$, a
>   polynomial equation having exponent three is called a cubic equation.
>   An equation of degree four is then unimaginatively called a quartic
>   equation, or sometimes (more commonly in older sources) a biquadratic
>   equation.